# Representation of denotational semantics of primitive recursive functions

Tags: haskell

Is there a way to represent the denotational semantics of primitive recursive functions (PRFs) in Haskell?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sort-of. We can encode primitive recursive functions with a Haskell class or GADT. We can then consider that a primitive recursive function is an equivalence class of the data type. The simplest equivalence is over the Haskell denotation semantics of the interpretation of the PRF. This representation is ultimately going to be inexact due to the denotational semantics of Haskell, but let's explore how close we can get.

#### Primitive Recursive Functions

We'll use the [definition of primitive recursive functions from Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function). A `PRF a` is a primitive recursive function with arity a, where a is a natural number.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

data PRF (a :: Nat) where
    Const ::                             PRF 'Z
    Succ  ::                             PRF ('S 'Z)
    Proj  :: BNat n                   -> PRF n
    Comp  :: PRF k  -> List k (PRF m) -> PRF m
    PRec  :: PRF k  -> PRF (S (S k))  -> PRF (S k)
```

`Const` constructs the constant function or arity zero which always returns 0. `Succ` is the successor function of arity one. `Proj` constructs the family of projection functions which each picks out one of their arguments after skipping the supplied number of arguments. `Comp` composes a function with a list of other functions that provide its arguments. `PRec` builds a function that pattern matches on the first argument. `PRec` applies the first function to the remaining arguments if the first argument is zero. If the first argument is not zero, it recurses into itself with the predecessor of the first argument as the first argument and returns the result of the second function applied to the predecessor of the first argument, the result of the recursion, and the remaining arguments. This is easier to see in the definition of a compiler from a `PRF` to a Haskell function.

```
compile :: PRF n -> List n Nat -> Nat
compile Const = const Z
compile Succ  = \(Cons n Nil) -> S n
compile (Proj n) = go n
    where
        go :: BNat n -> List n a -> a
        go BZero     (Cons h _) = h
        go (BSucc n) (Cons _ t) = go n t
compile (Comp f gs) = \ns -> f' . fmap ($ ns) $ gs'
    where
        gs' = fmap compile gs
        f'  = compile f
compile (PRec f g) = h
    where
        h (Cons Z t)     = f' t
        h (Cons (S n) t) = g' (Cons n (Cons (h (Cons n t)) t))
        f' = compile f
        g' = compile g
```

The above require the definitions for a natural number `Nat`, a natural number bounded by a type-level natural number, `BNat`, and a list with a type-level known length, `List`.

```
import qualified Data.Foldable as Foldable
import System.IO

data Nat = Z | S Nat
    deriving (Eq, Show, Read, Ord)

data List (n :: Nat) a where
    Nil   ::                  List 'Z     a
    Cons  :: a -> List n a -> List ('S n) a

instance Functor (List n) where
    fmap f Nil        = Nil
    fmap f (Cons h t) = Cons (f h) (fmap f t)    

-- A natural number in the range [0, n-1]
data BNat (n :: Nat)  where
    BZero ::           BNat ('S n)
    BSucc :: BNat n -> BNat ('S n)
```

We are now equipped to write our first primitive recursive functions. We'll write two examples for identity and addition.

```
ident :: PRF (S Z)
ident = Proj BZero

add :: PRF (S (S Z))
add = PRec ident (Comp Succ (Cons (Proj (BSucc BZero)) Nil))
```

Notice that we re-used declarations in Haskell to simplify writing these functions; we re-used `ident` in the definition of `add`. Ultimately the ability to use Haskell declarations will allow us to create infinite or non-total recursive structures that we can sneak into the `PRF` type.

We can write some example code to try out our `add` function. We'll be a little paranoid about evaluation order with `seq` and `hFlush` so that we can see just how wrong our representation is later.

```
mseq :: Monad m => a -> m a
mseq a = a `seq` return a

runPRF :: PRF n -> List n Nat -> IO ()
runPRF f i = 
    do
        putStrLn "Compiling function"
        hFlush stdout
        f' <- mseq $ compile f
        putStrLn "Running function"
        hFlush stdout
        n <- mseq $ f' i
        print n
```

If we run an example with `add` we get a nice, satisfying output

```
runPRF add (Cons (S (S Z)) (Cons (S (S (S Z))) Nil))

Compiling function
Running function
S (S (S (S (S Z))))
```

#### Haskell Declarations

There are some fun and ultimately disruptive things we can do with Haskell declarations. First we'll make pattern matching easier. It'd be nice to be able to use the pattern matching from `PRec` without providing a function that uses the recursive result. `match` will add that extra dummy argument for us.

```
match :: (Depths List k) => PRF k -> PRF (S k) -> PRF (S k)
match fz fs = PRec fz (addArgument (BSucc BZero) fs)
```

To do this it needs a helper function that adds the argument, `addArgument`, and a few other utilities to measure the size of a list with a known type, `Depths`, compare and convert `BNat`s, and prove that the incremented natural numbers are still under the new bound.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving #-}

class Depths f (n :: Nat) where
    depths :: f n (BNat n)

instance Depths List 'Z where
    depths = Nil

instance (Depths List n) => Depths List ('S n) where
    depths = Cons BZero (fmap BSucc depths)

deriving instance Eq (BNat n)
deriving instance Show (BNat n)
deriving instance Ord (BNat n)

bid :: BNat n -> BNat (S n)
bid BZero = BZero
bid (BSucc x) = BSucc (bid x)

addArgument :: (Depths List k) => BNat (S k) -> PRF k -> PRF (S k)
addArgument n f = Comp f . fmap p $ depths
    where
        p d =
            if d' >= n
            then Proj (BSucc d)
            else Proj d'
            where d' = bid d
```

This is really helpful when writing perfectly reasonable things like

```
nonZero :: PRF (S Z)
nonZero = match Const (Comp Succ (Cons (Comp Const Nil) Nil))

isZero :: PRF (S Z)
isZero = match (Comp Succ (Cons Const Nil)) (Comp Const Nil)

isOdd :: PRF (S Z)
isOdd = PRec Const (addArgument BZero isZero)
```

#### Recursive Haskell Declarations

We can also write very disruptive things that aren't just `undefined`. First, we'll define a `while` construct using recursion. We know that things built with `while` aren't supposed to exist in the closure of primitive recursive functions.

```
while :: (Depths List k) => PRF (S k) -> PRF (S k) -> PRF (S k)
while test step = goTest
    where
        --goTest :: PRF (S k)
        goTest  = Comp goMatch (Cons test (fmap Proj depths))
        --goMatch :: PRF (S (S k))
        goMatch = match (Proj BZero) (addArgument BZero goStep)
        --goStep :: PRF (S k)
        goStep  = Comp goTest (Cons step (fmap (Proj . BSucc) depths))
```

This lets us write a loop that is non-terminating for only some inputs.

```
infiniteLoop :: PRF (S Z)
infiniteLoop = while isOdd (Comp Succ (Cons Succ Nil))
```

If we run this for an even number, like `Z` or `S (S Z)`, it terminates returning the input. If we run it for an odd number, it never finishes.

```
runPRF infiniteLoop (Cons (S Z) Nil)
Compiling function
Running function
```

Because we were careful with the `seq` and `hFlush` we can be certain that the compiled value was inhabited in week head normal form by something that wasn't a primitive recursive function and wasn't simply `undefined`. This is because the `compile` step wasn't strict, and reduction to week head normal form didn't cause reduction all the way to head normal form. We could fix this by adding `seq`s to `compile`. I've changed only the two patterns that need it.

```
compile (Comp f gs) = f' `seq` gs' `seq` go
    where
        go = \ns -> f' . fmap ($ ns) $ gs'
        gs' = fmap compile gs
        f'  = compile f
compile (PRec f g) = f' `seq` g' `seq` h
    where
        h (Cons Z t)     = f' t
        h (Cons (S n) t) = g' (Cons n (Cons (h (Cons n t)) t))
        f' = compile f
        g' = compile g
```

This will essentially check that the `PRF` is finite when compiling it.

```
runPRF infiniteLoop (Cons Z Nil)
Compiling function
GHC stack-space overflow: current limit is 33632 bytes.
Use the `-K<size>' option to increase it.
```

#### Tidying up

None of the types we have talked about really represent primitive recursive function one-for-one. `PRF a` is inhabited by other things than the recursive structures defined above and `undefined`. It's also inhabited by multiple representations of the same primitive recursive functions. For example, the identity function has other definitions, including the composition of the predecessor function (which I didn't define) with the successor function. The result of compile, `List n Nat -> Nat`, is inhabited by any Haskell function with the same type, which will include all the partial recursive functions as well.

To hide that there are multiple representations of the same function we can use the same trick that Haskell does: hide the internals of the function. If the only way someone can inspect a `PRF` is to strictly compile it and apply it to something then nobody can tell the difference between the same primitive recursive function represented differently.

Converting our GADT into a typeclass and only exporting the class and `compile` would be enough to hide the constructors.

[Another interface](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27387931/414413) to export could be found if we twist our heads around a bit and notice that the axioms for primitive recursive functions are like the `Category` laws, `Arrow` without `arr` (in fact it has the opposite of `arr`), and a limited form of looping that only works on natural numbers.

This should be enough to convince you that it is almost possible. No matter what we do, we will still be plagued by an extra inhabitant, `undefined`. Further discussion of [how to make it nice would belong to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27387930/) that includes specific concerns for how it should be nice.

Comment: The GADT is a syntax for PRFs (not a semantics), and the result type of `compile` (namely `List n Nat -> Nat`) admits many more inhabitants than just PRFs. So which piece of this, exactly, plays the role of a denotational semantics for PRFs?

Comment: Where I'm headed with this is the PRF is denoted by "a `List n Nat -> Nat` obtained by calling something like `compile`". One way to say that in Haskell is with a data type that doesn't export its constructor and only exports a smart constructor. It will contain at least one more inhabitant, `undefined`, than PRFs. If not checked for finiteness it might also contain other things that aren't in PRF, including functions that terminate only for some inputs. Those are what I'm going to demonstrate in the next section.

Comment: Would you touch up and focus the question a bit to help reopen it? I had voted to close because I read the question an abstract question about denotational semantics *of* Haskell, but now I see there's a specific question that you've answered. (I must have missed your answer at the time; sorry!)