# Nice representation of primitive recursive functions in haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion

I argued in the [answer to a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27217795/414413) that it's possible to represent in Haskell the union of the [primitive recursive functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function) (PRFs) and the single extra value of ⊥ or `undefined`. This argument was based on a direct translation of an axiomatic construction of primitive recursive functions; it required a number of language extensions and type-level reasoning about the arity of functions. Is it possible to represent an equivalent set of primitive recursive functions in more idiomatic Haskell?

An idiomatic representation of PRFs should ideally be able to meet all of the following:

- Provide a `Category` instance
- Not need to mess around with type-level reasoning about function arity

In addition to the requirements for being primitive recursive

- Any function that's `undefined` for an input is `undefined` for all inputs. This restricts the set of PRFs to a single inescapable extra value of ⊥ instead of containing multiple partially recursive functions.This means that any definition of a `while` loop or similar partially recursive function should be `undefined`.

I noticed that the axioms for primitive recursive functions are like the `Category` laws, `Arrow` without `arr` (in fact it has the opposite of `arr`), and a limited form of looping that only works on natural numbers.

Comment: I see that you answered your own question after less than one minute, and nicely so. While allowed by SO rules as far as I know, it still looks weird -- the page looks more as a blog post than as a genuine question (IMHO). Still, thank you for sharing this.

Comment: @chi I only do it for questions that arise from discussion of another answer, but it still feels pretty weird to click the "share your knowledge, Q&A-style" button.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a very straightforward representation of primitive recursive functions in Haskell. It's a `newtype` for a function that we will assert is a correct-by-construction primitive recursive function. We don't export the constructor to prevent the construction of arbitrary functions which could be partially recursive. This technique is called a [smart constructor](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Smart_constructors).

```
module Data.PRF (
    -- We don't export the PRF constructor
    PRF (runPRF),
) where

newtype PRF b c = PRF {runPRF :: b -> c}
```

We also need to provide an interface by which to build `PRF`s. A `Category` instance will provide the composition portion of the extended composition required for PRFs.

```
import Prelude hiding (id, (.), fst, snd, succ)
import Control.Category

instance Category PRF where
    id = PRF id
    PRF f . PRF g = PRF $ f `seq` g `seq` (f . g)
```

The `seq`s require that `f` and `g` be in weak head normal form before any result can be calculated from them; if either function is `undefined` then the composition will be `undefined` as well.

The primitive recursive functions also require projection to select one argument from many. We'll view this as selecting one piece of data from a structure of data. If we use tuples instead of lists of known length the projection functions become `fst` and `snd`. Together with something like `Arrow`'s `(&&&)` to build tuples we can cover all the requirements for extended projection. PRFs are like "Arrow without `arr`"; `arr` would allow arbitrary partially recursive functions to be made into `PRFs`. We'll define the class of `ArrowLike` categories.

```
class Category a => ArrowLike a where
    fst   :: a (b, d) b
    snd   :: a (d, b) b
    (&&&) :: a b c -> a b c' -> a b (c,c')

    first :: a b c -> a (b, d) (c, d)
    first = (*** id)

    second :: a b c -> a (d,b) (d,c)
    second = (id ***)

    (***) :: a b c -> a b' c' -> a (b,b') (c,c')
    f *** g = (f . fst) &&& (g . snd)
```

The projection functions `fst` and `snd` take the place of `arr`. They are the only functions needed to describe `ArrowLike` behavior when combined with fanout `(&&&)`.

Before we provide an `ArrowLike` instance for `PRF` we'll say how ordinary functions `(->)` are `ArrowLike`

```
import qualified Prelude (fst, snd)

instance ArrowLike (->) where
    fst = Prelude.fst
    snd = Prelude.snd
    f &&& g = \b -> (f b, g b)
```

For `PRF`s we'll use the same inductive step we used in the definition of `(.)` for the `Category` instance and demand that both functions be in weak head normal form.

```
instance ArrowLike PRF where
    fst = PRF fst
    snd = PRF snd
    PRF f &&& PRF g = PRF $ f `seq` g `seq` (f &&& g)
```

Finally, we'll provide the primitive recursion itself.  We'll translate primitive recursion directly from the axiomatic definition using tuples instead of increasing function arities.

```
class ArrowLike a => PrimRec a where
    zero :: a b   Nat
    succ :: a Nat Nat
    prec :: a e c -> a (c, (Nat,e)) c -> a (Nat, e) c
```

`Nat` is a natural number given by `data Nat = Z | S Nat`. I'm choosing to view the constant function `zero` and the successor function as part of primitive recursion, the only way the `Nat` values they construct can be deconstructed or inspected is with `prec`. It is tempting to replace `zero` with `const :: c -> a b c`; this would be a fatal flaw as someone could introduce `infinity = S infinity` with `const` to turn `prec` into an infinite loop.

The partially recursive functions `(->)` support primitive recursion.

```
instance PrimRec (->) where
    zero = const Z
    succ = S
    prec f g = go
        where
            go (Z, d) = f d
            go (S n, d) = g (go (n, d), (n, d))
```

We'll define primitive recursion for `PRF` using the same inductive trick we used for `(.)` and `(&&&)`.

```
instance PrimRec PRF where
    zero = PRF zero
    succ = PRF succ
    prec (PRF f) (PRF g) = PRF $ f `seq` g `seq` prec f g
```

The primitive recursive functions are a `Category` with the ability to construct and deconstruct both tuples and natural numbers.

#### Examples

Primitive recursive functions such as `add` are easier to define with this interface.

```
import Prelude hiding (id, (.), fst, snd, succ)

import Control.Category
import Data.PRF

add :: PrimRec a => a (Nat, Nat) Nat
add = prec id (succ . fst)
```

We can still define useful functions like `match` which helps build primitive recursive functions that branch on whether a natural is zero.

```
match :: PrimRec a => a b c -> a (Nat, b) c -> a (Nat, b) c
match fz fs = prec fz (fs . snd)
```

Using `match` we can easily quickly test if a value is `Z` and eventually whether it is odd

```
one :: PrimRec a => a b Nat
one = succ . zero

nonZero :: PrimRec a => a Nat Nat
nonZero = match zero one . (id &&& id)

isZero :: PrimRec a => a Nat Nat
isZero = match one zero . (id &&& id)

isOdd :: PrimRec a => a Nat Nat
isOdd = prec zero (isZero . fst) . (id &&& id)
```

We can still write Haskell declarations that are generally recursive, but all `PRF`s built this way will be `undefined`.

```
while :: PrimRec a => a s Nat -> a s s -> a s s
while test step = goTest
    where
        goTest = goMatch . (test &&& id)
        goMatch = match id (goStep . snd)
        goStep = goTest . step
```

This function, `infiniteLoop`, would fail to terminate only for odd inputs.

```
infiniteLoop :: PrimRec a => a Nat Nat
infiniteLoop = while isOdd (succ . succ)
```

When running our examples, we will be careful about the evaluation order like in the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27217795/414413).

```
import System.IO

mseq :: Monad m => a -> m a
mseq a = a `seq` return a

run :: Show b => PRF a b -> a -> IO ()
run f i = 
    do
        putStrLn "Compiling function"
        hFlush stdout
        f' <- mseq $ runPRF f
        putStrLn "Running function"
        hFlush stdout
        n <- mseq $ f' i
        print n
```

We can evaluate `PRF`s that were defined conveniently in terms of `match`.

```
run isOdd (S $ S $ S Z)

Compiling function
Running function
S Z
```

But the function defined by `infiniteLoop` is `undefined` in general, not just for odd values.

```
run infiniteLoop (Z)

Compiling function
```

Comment: This reminds me of [Generalized Arrows are Multi Level Languages](http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/4259). Very nice!

Comment: @J.Abrahamson That's a very interesting paper, thanks. `ArrowLike` is approximately a `GArrow` with duplicate, copy, and swap and would thus be sitting in about the same place as `GArrowSTKC` for the simply typed kappa calculus. They share the approach of using a "standard instance `Arrow (->)` ... as an evaluation mechanism for guest
languages which happen to be a subset of Haskell".