# Generalising ($) like Control.Category generalises (.)

Tags: haskell, category-abstractions

I had a thought to generalise `($)` like `Control.Category` generalises `(.)`, and I've done so with the code at the end of this post ([also ideone](https://ideone.com/Uc1398)).

In this code I've created a class called `FunctionObject`. This class has a function `($)` with the following signature:

```
($) :: f a b -> a -> b
```

Naturally I make `(->)` an instance of this class so `$` continues to work with ordinary functions.

But this allows you to make special functions that, for example, know their own inverse, as the example below shows.

I've concluded there's one of three possibilities:

1. I'm the first to think of it.
2. Someone else has already done it and I'm reinventing the wheel.
3. It's a bad idea.

Option 1 seems unlikely, and my searches on [hayoo](http://hayoo.fh-wedel.de/) didn't reveal option 2, so I suspect option 3 is most likely, but if someone could explain why that is it would be good.

```
import Prelude hiding ((.), ($))
import Control.Category ((.), Category)

class FunctionObject f where
  ($) :: f a b -> a -> b

infixr 0 $

instance FunctionObject (->) where
  f $ x = f x

data InvertibleFunction a b = 
   InvertibleFunction (a -> b) (b -> a)

instance Category InvertibleFunction where
  (InvertibleFunction f f') . (InvertibleFunction g g') =
    InvertibleFunction (f . g) (g' . f')

instance FunctionObject InvertibleFunction where
  (InvertibleFunction f _) $ x = f $ x

inverse (InvertibleFunction f f') = InvertibleFunction f' f

add :: (Num n) => n -> InvertibleFunction n n
add n = InvertibleFunction (+n) (subtract n)

main = do
  print $ add 2 $ 5 -- 7
  print $ inverse (add 2) $ 5 -- 3
```

Comment: Check the `ArrowApply` typeclass at https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/base/Control-Arrow.html

Comment: @AJFarmar `ArrowApply` is equivalent to `Monad`

Comment: You may also like to look into [cartesian closed categories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_closed_category), which are those categories that have an "application" operation (and a few other supporting constructs).

Comment: A similar question (with the same usage example: invertible functions) has been discussed at [Why isn't there a typeclass for functions?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/215497/11591).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two abstractions used for things like this in Haskell, one usings `Arrow`s and the other `Applicative`s. Both can be broken down into smaller parts than those used in `base`.

---

If you go in the `Arrow` direction and [break down the capabilities of `Arrow`s into component pieces](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Farxiv.org%2Fabs%2F1007.2885&ei=52KRVaLWAoTwoASV44OYCA&usg=AFQjCNF7TMVyJnsjsrNguJGMYjCIYaBXRw&sig2=uB6vQrlIINYTTpim5p5CAA), you'd have a separate class for those arrows that are able to lift arbitrary functions into the arrow.

```
class ArrowArr a where
    arr :: (b -> c) -> a b c
```

This would be the opposite of `ArrowArr`, arrows where any arbitrary arrow can be dropped to a function.

```
class ArrowFun a where
    ($) :: a b c -> (b -> c)
```

If you just split `arr` off of `Arrow` you are left with [arrow like categories that can construct and deconstruct tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27387931/414413).

```
class Category a => ArrowLike a where
    fst   :: a (b, d) b
    snd   :: a (d, b) b
    (&&&) :: a b c -> a b c' -> a b (c,c')
```

---

If you go in the `Applicative` direction this is a [`Copointed`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pointed-2.0.2/docs/Data-Copointed.html) "`Applicative` without `pure`" (which goes by the name [`Apply`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/semigroupoids-5.0.0.2/docs/Data-Functor-Apply.html#t:Apply)).

```
class Copointed p where Source
    copoint :: p a -> a

class Functor f => Apply f where
  (<.>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
```

When you go this way you typically drop the `Category` for functions and instead have a type constructor `C a` representing values (including function values) constructed according to a certain set of rules.

Answer (score 12):

`$` applies morphisms to *values*. The concept of a value seems trivial, but actually, general categories need to have no such notion. Morphisms are values (arrow-values... whatever), but objects (types) needn't actually contain any elements.

However, in many categories, there is a special object, the [terminal object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_and_terminal_objects). In **Hask**, this is the `()` type. You'll notice that functions `() -> a` are basically equivalent to `a` values themselves. Categories in which this works are called [well-pointed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-pointed_category). So really, the fundamental thing you need for something like `$` to make sense is

```
class Category c => WellPointed c where
  type Terminal c :: *
  point :: a -> Terminal c `c` a
  unpoint :: Terminal c `c` a -> a
```

Then you can define the application operator by

```
($) :: WellPointed c => c a b -> a -> b
f $ p = unpoint $ f . point p
```

---

The obvious instance for `WellPointed` is of course **Hask** itself:

```
instance WellPointed (->) where
  type Terminal c = ()
--point :: a -> () -> a
  point a () = a
--unpoint :: (() -> a) -> a
  unpoint f = f ()
```

The other well-known category, `Kleisli`, is *not* an instance of `WellPointed` as I wrote it (it allows `point`, but not `unpoint`). But there are plenty of categories which would make for a good `WellPointed` instance, if they could properly be implemented in Haskell at all. Basically, all the categories of mathematical functions with particular properties ([**Lin<sub>*K*</sub>**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_of_modules#Example:_the_category_of_vector_spaces), [**Grp**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_of_groups), [{{•}, **Top**}](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointed_space)...). The reason these aren't directly expressible as a `Category` is that they can't have any Haskell type as an object; newer category libraries like [categories](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/categories) or [constrained-categories](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories) do allow this. For instance, [I have implemented this](https://github.com/leftaroundabout/manifolds/blob/5e191c413d9facd18bb5c72fd850b08e0c96cf7c/manifolds/Data/Manifold/PseudoAffine.hs#L435):

```
instance (MetricScalar s) => WellPointed (Differentiable s) where
  unit = Tagged Origin
  globalElement x = Differentiable $ \Origin -> (x, zeroV, const zeroV)
  const x = Differentiable $ \_ -> (x, zeroV, const zeroV)
```

As you see, [the class interface](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.2.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow-Constrained.html#t:WellPointed) is actually a bit different from what I wrote above. There isn't one universally accepted way of implementing such stuff in Haskell yet... in `constrained-categories`, the `$` operator actually works more like what Cirdec described.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Can you add an instance for 'WellPointed'?

Comment: May I recommend using "final" instead of "terminal"? The meaning of the latter depends on who's writing it.

Comment: What are the fors and againsts of making `WellPointed` `Category`'s direct subclass? Why wasn't it chosen for `Control.Arrow.Constrained`? [Related.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63060108/wellpointed-for-dual-to-prearrow-class)

Comment: @ZhiltsoffIgor you mean why is it currently `PreArrow a => WellPointed a` instead of `Category a => WellPointed a`? Well, I kind of started from the view to cartesian closed categories and ravelled it up. But you're right, mathematically it would actually be nicer to put `WellPointed` higher in the hierarchy, separate from the `Cartesian` branch, and have a dedicated `class (PreArrow a, WellPointed a, UnitObject a ~ Terminal a) => CartesianClosed a`, though I may be overlooking some practical issue right now. — If you would like that changed, feel free to file a pull request.

Comment: @leftaroundabout truth be told, I feel a bit lost. Haven't we got `Control.Category.Constrained.Curry` for cartesian closed categories ([at least locally small ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62994618/why-is-it-fair-to-think-of-just-locally-small-cartesian-closed-categories-in-has))? I guess cartesian closed categories could be written down in Haskell different ways, yet `Curry` always felt very neat. Or am I missing the point of some the classes?

Comment: Ah yes, `Curry`. It is rather me that's lost, not you! I think that's the reason why I made no class actually named `CartesianClosed`: I couldn't decide where to put it in the hierarchy. — Goes to show the problems you get when kind of balancing between _keeping it close to the `base.Arrow` hierarchy_ and _making it proper mathematically category theory_.