# Control.Category, what does >>> and <<< mean?

Tags: haskell, function-composition, category-theory, arrows, category-abstractions

I am following [this blog](https://lstephen.wordpress.com/2008/02/14/a-simple-haskell-web-server/), to write a simple http server in haskell,

Usage of `>>>` is not clear to me. What does this code snippet do?

```
handleHttpConnection r c = runKleisli
    (receiveRequest >>> handleRequest r >>> handleResponse) c >>
    close c
```

Similary on [this link](http://newartisans.com/2012/10/arrows-are-simpler-than-they-appear/), i am seeing `<<<`

```
let h =     arr (++ "!")
          <<< arr foo
          <<< Kleisli bar
          <<< arr id
```

What does `<<<` and `>>>` do? ([Hackage document](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Control-Category.html) is very concise and couldn't get much out of it.)

Comment: That blog has a [link](https://wiki.haskell.org/Arrow_tutorial#Kleisli_Arrows) to an article about Kleisli Arrows that seems useful. I believe these two operators represent some kind of function composition (for Arrows which are functions). For other kinds of Arrows, I'm not sure, as arrows are a little strange to me.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As Hackage and/or Hoogle will tell you,

```
(>>>) :: Category k => a`k`b  -> b`k`c  -> a`k`c
(<<<) :: Category k => b`k`c  -> a`k`b  -> a`k`c
```

Observe that the latter is actually the same as

```
(.)   :: Category k => b`k`c  -> a`k`b  -> a`k`c
```

or, in its `Prelude` form, specialised to the **Hask** category of functions,

```
(.)   ::               (b->c) -> (a->b) -> (a->c)
```

So, `<<<` and `>>>` simply compose functions, or more generally morphisms/arrows.

`<<<` composes in the same direction as the familiar `.`, while `>>>` flips the arguments so that “data flows from left to right”.

---

Now, what arrow composition *means*, for categories other than **Hask**, depends of course on the category. `Kleisli IO` is an easy to understand example: say we have a pure function

```
pipe :: Double -> String
pipe = show . sqrt . (+2) . abs
```

As I said, this can also be written

```
pipe = abs >>> (+2) >>> sqrt >>> show
```

Now, if you want to add primitive IO logging (like you might in an imperative language), you can introduce

```
type (-|>) = Kleisli IO

abs', add2', sqrt' :: Num a => a -|> a
show' :: Show a => a -|> String

abs'  = Kleisli $ \x -> do putStrLn ("Absolute of "++show x++"...")
                           return $ abs x
add2' = Kleisli $ \x -> do putStrLn ("Add 2 to "++show x++"...")
                           return $ x + 2
sqrt' = Kleisli $ \x -> do putStrLn ("Square root of "++show x++"...")
                           return $ sqrt x
show' = Kleisli $ \x -> do putStrLn ("Show "++show x++"...")
                           return $ show x
```

With that, you can define

```
pipe' :: Double -|> String
```

in *exactly* the same way as before, i.e.

```
pipe' = abs' >>> add2' >>> sqrt' >>> show'
```

But you'll now get the intermediate results printed out as a side-effect.

Comment: that is a beautiful example... thanks... why would someone do `show . sqrt . (+2) . abs` instead of `show $ sqrt $ (+2) $ abs n`. i know, dot `.` is all about some function composition , but does it solve any problem that `$` doesn't solve?

Comment: @MadhavanKumar: well, this is in fact an excellent example for what `$` doesn't solve: it can't be generalised to work in arbitrary categories. ([Some categories have a generalisation of `$`, but most don't – including `Kleisli`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31118949/generalising-like-control-category-generalises/31120454#31120454).) Apart from that, point-free style is often more concise, can be somewhat easier refactored, and doesn't require you to introduce a variable name... however, these aren't always advantages; sometimes point-free is harder to understand (“pointless code”).

Comment: Then, are `<=<` and `>=>` also special cases of `<<<` and `>>>` that work for monads?

Comment: I have written code similar to your example, but using `<*>` and `<$>` in the applicative which is a composition of of the applicative for function (composition) and for the effect I'm interested in (logging in your example), i.e., Compose (a->) (Reader ..). Perhaps you are cleaner

Comment: @imz--IvanZakharyaschev: Yes, I think so, only that `>=>` don't need that `Kleisli` newtype wrapper around the monadic function.