# WellPointed for dual to PreArrow class

Tags: haskell, typeclass, category-theory

In [Control.Arrow.Constrained](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.2.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow-Constrained.html) there is a class [`WellPointed`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.2.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow-Constrained.html#t:WellPointed):

> Unlike with [`Morphism`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.2.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow-Constrained.html#t:Morphism) and [`PreArrow`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.2.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow-Constrained.html#t:PreArrow), a literal dual of [`WellPointed`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.2.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow-Constrained.html#t:WellPointed) does not seem useful.

Which is true as the duality for the following methods seems a bit weird:

```
globalElement :: ObjectPoint a x => x -> a (UnitObject a) x

unit :: CatTagged a (UnitObject a)

const :: (Object a b, ObjectPoint a x) => x -> a b x
```

But why would not we like (for example) having `const` for "choice" arrows (like having some constant error information which could be then tagged)? Having `unit` in this hierarchy does not seem weird too as we have already started speaking of units in [`CoCartesian`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.2.0.0/docs/Control-Category-Constrained.html#t:CoCartesian) when working with 2 sum-types: `Bool ≅ unit + unit` and `Maybe a ≅ unit + a`.

So, how do we deal with this? Are we somehow guaranteed to be able to write down all the instances for [`WellPointed`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.2.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow-Constrained.html#t:WellPointed) superclasses (and, if it is so, does it have something to do with `Arrow` being `ArrowChoice`'s superclass)? Also, why do we define those methods in [`PreArrow`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.2.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow-Constrained.html#t:PreArrow)'s subclass? Why could not have we moved them *"down"* the hierarchy?

---

Edit: I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31120454/11143763) by [leftaroundabout](https://stackoverflow.com/users/745903/leftaroundabout) (who is the author of [Control.Arrow.Constrained](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.2.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow-Constrained.html)) where he writes [`WellPointed`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.2.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow-Constrained.html#t:WellPointed) down as the direct `Category`'s subclass. Why were things written down another way in [Control.Arrow.Constrained](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.2.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow-Constrained.html)?

Comment: I'll add [noise to the system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/351274/can-i-suggest-questions-in-the-comments/351280?noredirect=1#comment1176497_351280) and mention [this excellent answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2359157/284619) in Math SE that uses Haskell

Comment: @uhoh very interesting, thank you.