# Does Pointed for categories embody well-pointed categories?

Tags: haskell, category-theory, arrows

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31120454/11143763) [leftaroundabout](https://stackoverflow.com/users/745903/leftaroundabout) speaks of well-pointed categories. In the post, the `WellPointed` class is a subclass of `Category`, unlike [`Control.Arrow.Constrained.WellPointed`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.2.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow-Constrained.html#t:WellPointed) (the reasons for this we discussed in the comments under [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31120454/11143763)):

```
class Category c => WellPointed c where
  type Terminal c :: *
  point :: a -> Terminal c `c` a
  unpoint :: Terminal c `c` a -> a
```

As far as I understand, this code could be generalised a bit with [`Data.Pointed.Pointed`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pointed-5/docs/Data-Pointed.html) and [`Data.Copointed.Copointed`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pointed-5/docs/Data-Copointed.html) (there is [a HaskellWiki on why using `Pointed` is not the best idea](https://wiki.haskell.org/Why_not_Pointed%3F), yet we are speaking pure theory, not library design).

But why do we need [`Copointed`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pointed-5/docs/Data-Copointed.html) interface for well-pointed categories? In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-pointed_category) it says that the well-pointed category simply has enough points to tell different morphisms apart. If we have `point` (or `globalElement` in [`Control.Arrow.Constrained.WellPointed`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.2.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow-Constrained.html#t:WellPointed)'s terms), we would have the whole domain of any morphisms lifted into the category, including the points where different morphisms are unequal for every pair. [leftaroundabout](https://stackoverflow.com/users/745903/leftaroundabout) notes that `Monad m => Kleisli m` does not allow `copoint`, but it seems to me it is well-pointed (`Monad m => Kleisli m` is an instance of [`Control.Arrow.Constrained.WellPointed`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.2.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow-Constrained.html#t:WellPointed)).

So, my questions are:

- Can well-pointed categories be written down as instances of `Pointed` (of course, partially-applied to some unit - in [`constrained-categories`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.2.0.0/docs/Control-Category-Constrained.html) we do that with [`UnitObject k`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/constrained-categories-0.2.0.0/docs/Control-Category-Constrained.html#t:UnitObject)).
- If not, how?

Comment: "But why do we need Copointed interface for well-pointed categories?" Where does it say we do?

Comment: @Li-yaoXia the definition leftaroundabout gave has `unpoint`, which matches `copoint` for `Category`. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Ok I see. I'd chalk it off to `Pointed` and `Copointed` being awfully vague abstractions, so they are going to match a lot of things but there's not much insight to be gained from it.

Comment: @Li-yaoXia sorry, I do not quite get you. You mean that `Pointed` and `Copointed` being vague causes `Copointed`'s interface in `WellPointed` or `Pointed` for categories being `WellPointed` (my question is latter true)? I cannot see how we are lacking insight as `WellPointed` plus `Control.Arrow.Constrained`'s `PreArrow` give us `Arrow` without `arr` (as far as I understand). Can you please, elaborate on your points?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood the actual question. I was commenting on "this code could be generalised a bit with Data.Pointed.Pointed and Data.Copointed.Copointed" and saying that's it's not a worthwhile generalization/reformulation. That's besides your main point anyway, which is about the purpose of `unpoint` and the relationship of those Haskell `WellPointed` classes with the wikipedia definition, which I don''t know the answer to.